# Obtener un array ordenado con índices en lugar de valores

Tags: java, funciones, ordenamiento

Tengo un ejercicio que pide:
"Dado un array, obtener uno nuevo ordenado descendentemente (de mayor a menor), pero a través de sus índices"; es decir, si tengo el array `[2, 5, 1]`, la función me debería devolver un array con los valores `[1, 0, 2]`. Que correspondería al orden al que debo acceder a los índices del primer array  para hacerlo ordenadamente de forma descendente.

La idea que se me ha ocurrido es ir ordenando una copia del array e ir almacenando el índice que he ordenado en un nuevo array, que será el que devuelva, pero no funciona. He probado varias otras cosas, pero no termino de entender cómo podría hacerse.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int[] nums = {8, 7, 1, 8};
        final int[] sortedIndexes = seleccion(nums);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortedIndexes));
    }
    

    public static int[] seleccion(int[] v) {
        final int[] array = Arrays.copyOf(v, v.length);
        final int[] sortedIndexes =  new int[v.length];
        Arrays.fill(sortedIndexes, v.length - 1);
        int n = v.length; 
        int posmax;
        

        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            posmax = i;
            
            for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
                if (array[j] > array[posmax]) {
                    posmax = j;

                }
            }
                
            permuta(array, sortedIndexes, i, posmax);
        } 
        return sortedIndexes;
    }
    
    public static void permuta(int[] array, int[] arrayIndex, int index, int posmax) {
        final int tempValue = array[index];
        array[index] = array[posmax];
        array[posmax] = tempValue;
        arrayIndex[posmax] = index;

    }
}
```

El mayor problema para hacer el ejercicio es que no puedo usar nada que no sean bucles, condicionales o arrays.

Comment: por el enunciado que pones ,dado [2, 5, 1] ¿¿no debería devolver [1,0,2] ???

Comment: Muchas gracias, tienes razón. Lo he corregido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer "modificando" algún algoritmo de ordenamiento y guardardo los cambios de índice que vayas haciendo.

```java
public static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int t = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = t;
}

public static void qs(int[] indexes, int[] arr, int start, int end) {
    if (start >= end)
        return;

    int pivot = arr[end - 1];
    int wall = start;

    for (int i = start; i < end; ++i) {
        if (arr[i] >= pivot) {
            swap(arr, i, wall);
            swap(indexes, i, wall);
            ++wall;
        }
    }

    qs(indexes, arr, start, wall - 1);
    qs(indexes, arr, wall, end);
}

public static int[] qs(int[] arr) {
    int[] indexes = new int[arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; indexes[i] = i++) ;

    qs(indexes, arr, 0, arr.length);
    return indexes;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    int[] arr = {2, 5, 1, 4, 3, 7, 0, -1};
    int[] idxs = qs(arr);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(idxs));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

En este caso hice quicksort y dentro del único `if` que hay no solamente cambio los índices en el arreglo con los valores a ordenar, sino también cambio los índices en el arreglo de índices, que es a final de cuentas lo que deseas.

De esta forma, al final el arreglo retornado por `qs(int[])` son los índices que ordenarían al arreglo original, y de paso se ordena el arreglo.

El código imprime

```
[5, 1, 3, 4, 0, 2, 6, 7]
[7, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1]
```

El comportamiento asintótico es `O(n log(n))`, aunque el espacial se vuelve `O(n)` porque tenemos que guardar un nuevo arreglo de los índices.

Perdona que no haya explicado a detalle todo, aprenderás más si descifras por ti solo el código. Por cierto, puedes eficientar aún más el algoritmo si usas quicksort con 3 particiones (3 particiones de valores menores, iguales y mayores al pivote).

Comment: Mil gracias. Estudiaré el algoritmo como recomiendas!

Answer (score 1):

podrías intentar algo así:

```
// Para pruebas
//const arrayOriginal = [4,2, 8,5, 1,6];
//Resultado esperado 2 5 3 0 1 4

const arrayOriginal = [2, 5, 1];
// Resultado esperado [1, 0, 2]

const tabla = [];

function orderByIndex() {
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayOriginal.length; i++) {
    tabla.push({ position: i, number: arrayOriginal[i] });
}
tabla.sort((a, b) => b.number - a.number)
return tabla.map(elem=>elem.position)
}

orderByIndex();
```

Básicamente  son 3 pasos importantes:

Genero una tabla que es un array de objetos (un diccionario), cada objeto tiene su posición(que sería el índice en el arrayOriginal) y su número (por el cual vamos a ordenar inicialmente).

Tabla al crearse:

```
0: {position: 0, number: 2}
1: {position: 1, number: 5}
2: {position: 2, number: 1}
```

Luego ordeno los objetos por su número (number)

Tabla al ordenar por numero:

```
0: {position: 1, number: 5}
1: {position: 0, number: 2}
2: {position: 2, number: 1}
```

Finalmente por cada objeto de la tabla ordenada anteriormente. devuelvo su position con un map, que devuelve un nuevo array con los valores [1,0,2].

Espero te sirva para lo que necesites hacer, quedo a las ordenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta. El problema radica en que no puedo usar ni mapas para hacer el ejercicio. Bucles, condicionales y arrays, poco más. De todos modos, muchas gracias.

Comment: Para el sort podés usar algo llamado Buble Sort es muy sencillo solo con bucles y condiciones, el map está actuando como un for comun, lo podés reemplazar, si llego temprano a casa, te paso otra versión