# ¿Cómo hago para que solo me muestre los 5 primeros números menores y su posición?

Tags: java

Este algoritmo guarda 1000 números aleatorios del 0 al 36 y guarda sus repeticiones y también el porcentaje de cada repetición

Ejemplo: "El 4 salió 23 veces y su porcentaje es 2,3%".

Como lo tengo ahora me ordena de menor a mayor las repeticiones y necesito que solo sean las 5 primeras repeticiones menores (me esta guardando de menor a mayor las repeticiones) y que me diga la posiciones de esas 5 menores repeticiones (seria por ejemplo "El 5 se ha repetido 32 veces).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int nmenor = 37, nmenor2 = 37, nmenor3 = 37, nmenor4 = 37, nmenor5 = 37;
        int pos = 37, posi2 = 37, posi3 = 37, posi4 = 0, posi5 = 0;

        double p1, p2, p3, p4, p5;

        int[] numeros = new int[1000];
        int[] posiciones = new int[37];

        System.out.println("Bienvenido");

        for (int i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            numeros[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 37);
            posiciones[numeros[i]]++;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < posiciones.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ha salido el " + (i) + " -> " + posiciones[i] + " veces");
        }
        int temporal = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < posiciones.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < (posiciones.length - i); j++) {
                if (posiciones[j - 1] > posiciones[j]) {
                    temporal = posiciones[j - 1];
                    posiciones[j - 1] = posiciones[j];
                    posiciones[j] = temporal;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(posiciones));
```

Comment: Revisa la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/506694/193364) que dieron en otra pregunta similar